# asp:textbox - разрешить ввод только чисел и букв

Tags: asp.net-webforms

Нашёл много примеров для asp:textBox с применением RegularExpressionValidator. Но они не подходят. При использовании валидатора у нас выводится сообщение об ошибке, но запрещённый символ, например запятая, всё равно появляются в поле.

Пробовал также на asp:TextBox вешать на событие onkeypress js функцию

```
function OnKeyPressTest (event) {
var char = event.key;

var exp = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
var isWrongChar = exp.test(char);
if (isWrongChar) {
        return false;
    } 
return true;
};
```

Код функции отрабатывает правильно, при вводе в поле не букв и не цифр возвращает false, но не валидный символ всё равно отображается в поле.

Можно ли как-то полностью исключить возможность ввода символов кроме букв и цифр?

Answer (score 0):

ответ нашёл в этой статье - 

[ASP.NET: Фильтрация ввода в Textbox](http://www.hardline.ru/4/38/4839/)

фишка в строке window.event.returnValue = false;